# Executing cmdlet Get-ClusterGroup from C#

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

Hi I'm trying to execute the Get-ClusterGroup cmdlet from C# 4.0. I've used the following code

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "failoverclusters"});

Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
myRunSpace.Open();

Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

Command myCommand = new Command("Get-ClusterGroup");
pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);

Console.WriteLine("Invoking Command");
Collection commandResult = pipeLine.Invoke();

foreach (PSObject resultObject in commandResult)
{
Console.WriteLine(resultObject.ToString());
}
myRunSpace.Close();
```

But getting the following error

The term 'Get-ClusterGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

It will be great if someone can show me the where I'm missing the logic or where is the problem in my code

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ClusterGroup` is a Powershell Commandlet, not an .exe file. You can invoke Powershell commands from .NET using the `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` class, as described on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please, see my code, I've used C# to execute the powershell cmdlet